# react-beautiful-dnd: Unable to find draggable with id: x (Solved)

Tags: javascript, react-beautiful-dnd

### ** ***SOLVED*** **

### I was able to solve the problem. As this was my first time programming in JS, I didn't realize that I had `StrictMode` enabled in my `index.js` file, once I deleted it, the program worked just fine. (File at the end)

I am following a YouTube tutorial to make a Kanbanboard with react-beautiful-dnd and I can't make the elements move. As soon as I click any of them I get the error:

```
'Unable to find draggable with id: x'
```

I've following the [tutorial](https://youtu.be/SJTazZUQVDE?si=WmfRRO62c1l8sThi) but making changes as I wanted to make a calendar, but the logic is almost the same, and I can't find what the problem may be.

I was trying to make the elements move between arrays, but I can't even drag them. And the error mentioned is the only error that the console shows.

Also, I've tried to debug using `console.log` and it seems that the program goes through the lists multiple times.

Here is my [sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/matulibe/organizador-horarios/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6rnrt000j356i6kf6f7mu%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6rnrt000e356ijutw687d%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6rnrt000i356iaanfxgkp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6rnrt000g356iz63zjva4%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B41.596671107764195%252C58.403328892235805%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clmf6rnrt000e356ijutw687d%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6rnrt000e356ijutw687d%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmf6srtt00u2356ipv795q7j%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6rnrs000d356il5ucx7vb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FActividad.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6srtt00u2356ipv795q7j%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FDia.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6t32m013v356ifztsh5w2%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FPlanilla.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6tcwd01co356i3idenckq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf7fmj80335356iftya3l5w%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clmf6rnrt000g356iz63zjva4%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6rnrt000g356iz63zjva4%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmf6sh5q00nk356i4iofc9g6%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6sh5q00nk356i4iofc9g6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clmf6rnrt000i356iaanfxgkp%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6rnrt000i356iaanfxgkp%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmf6sdtr00jz356ig9d6mhxf%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6rnrt000h356i64y38j02%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clmf6rn6i000se7gvgkps9opx%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmf6sdtr00jz356ig9d6mhxf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

```
import React from "react";
import { Droppable} from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import Actividad from "./Actividad";

export default function Dia({ nombre, actividades, id }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{nombre}</h1>
            <Droppable droppableId={id} className='dia-container'>
                {(provided) => (
                    <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
                        {actividades.map((actividad, index) => (
                            <Actividad key={actividad.id} index={index} actividad={actividad} />
                        ))}
                        {provided.placeholder}
                    </div>
                )}

            </Droppable>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Droppable} from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import Actividad from "./Actividad";

export default function Dia({ nombre, actividades, id }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{nombre}</h1>
            <Droppable droppableId={id} className='dia-container'>
                {(provided) => (
                    <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
                        {actividades.map((actividad, index) => (
                            <Actividad key={actividad.id} index={index} actividad={actividad} />
                        ))}
                        {provided.placeholder}
                    </div>
                )}

            </Droppable>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd"; 

export default function Actividad({actividad, index}){
    return(
        <Draggable draggableId={`${actividad.id}`} key={actividad.id} index={index}>
            {(provided) => (
                <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
                    <div>
                        <h3>{actividad.nombre}</h3>
                    </div>
                    {provided.placeholder}
                </div>
            )}
        </Draggable>
    );
}
```

`Planilla` would the board where the columns are placed, this columns being `Dia` which is a drdoppable object. And `Actividades` would be the draggable elements.

This is what was wrong:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode> ===> This was the issue, must be deleted
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is a requirement on SO that you post your code directly to this site so that it can be preserved for others who might have the same question